# Несколько видов регистрации/входа на сайте

Tags: python, django, авторизация, регистрация, логин

Ребят, привет! Подскажите пожалуйста идею, как правильней реализовать функционал. Есть 2 вида регистрации/входа пользователей на сайт(е):

1. Назовем его(ее) "обычная(ый)" (т. е. через логин(эмэйл), пароль ). Для этой категории юзеров будет ограниченный функционал ресурса;
2. Через специальный файл(к примеру файл *.dat с информацией о пользователе; а именно пользователя характеризует какой-то uuid, пропущенный через хэш-функцию, например; т. е. уже не запишешь это в username, а нужна отдельная таблица для этого атрибута + еще много другой информации о пользователе). А для этих товарищей доступно все на сайте.

Что для этого требуется?

1. Отказаться от стандартной регистрации Джанги(тут возникли проблемы с бэкэндом; я задавал вопрос на форуме уже http://djbook.ru/forum/topic/4631/);
2. Написать свои формы для рег/входа (тут понятно);
3. Написать свои модели(как указать свои 2 модели в settings.py???);
4. Написать свои вьюшки и бэкэнды;

Вопросы:

1. Нужно ли выделять 2 таблицы под разные категории пользователей?
2. Как указать "пермишнсы" для юзеров; к примеру одни пользователи могут кликать по какой-то абстрактной кнопке, а другие нет?
3. На каком этапе определять, какой юзер "стучится" на сайт; на фронте или не бэке?

ЗЫ: Сразу скажу, что вопросы задаются не из ряда "решите за меня". Я не преследую эту цель. Мне важны дельные советы, ссылки, ссорцы где можно покопаться, какие-то идеи и соображения из личного опыта хотя бы по некоторым вопросам с которыми Вам приходилось сталкиваться.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Не нужно, достаточно поля вроде "is_authorised_with_certificate". Это поле будет изменяться на этапе аутентификации пользователя. За основу можно взять простой пример из документации (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-in):

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

def my_view(request):
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            # Redirect to a success page.
        else:
            # Return a 'disabled account' error message
            ...
    else:
        # Return an 'invalid login' error message.
        ...
```

Функция login запишет в БД нужную информацию, присвоит шифрованный cookie. Соответственно, если пользователь предоставил файл, то можно на этом же этапе проверять его и выставлять поле "is_authorised_with_certificate" в true.
Альтернативно можно создать группу "trusted_users" и помещать пользователя в нее.

2) Проверять поле "is_authorised_with_certificate".

3) Проверка пользователей с помощью JavaScript не имеет смысла - пользователь полностью контролирует браузер и может подставить любые cookie, перебирать их, имеет доступ к скриптам.

4) Можно не изобретать велосипед с шифрованными uuid и отдавать защищенную часть только по https - тогда авторизация и проверки будут происходить еще на этапе установки соединения и все, что касается сертификатов и возможных проблем отлично гуглится. И пользователю нужно только один раз настроить свой браузер. Более того, ничего в джанге писать не нужно - все сделает настроенный сервер. Если такая версия с двумя разными страницами для разных протоколов кажется неудачной, то можно на этапе проверки сертификата на сервере утсанавливать особое поле в HTTP заголовке. Что-то типа CERTIFICATE_IS_CORRECT. В джанге написать свой middleware, который бы проверял данный заголовок. Если он есть, значит сертификат верен. Если его нет, значит сертификат не был предоставлен или неверен.

5) Свои модели в настройках указывать не нужно.

Comment: Спасибо большое за развернутый ответ!

Comment: @jaroslav, судя по профилю, вы не отмечаете ответы на ваши вопросы как принятые. Отмеченные вопросы говорят сообществу о том, что проблема решена, дают репутации вам и ответившему. На stackoverflow голосавание за полезные ответы и вопросы, принятие ответов - это такой способ сказать "спасибо". В случае появления более полезного ответа всегда можно откатить принятие и отметить уже новый вопрос. Отметить ответ как принятый можно нажатием на серую галку, откатить - соответсвенно нажатием на зеленую галку.

Comment: Окей! Буду иметь ввиду. Спасибо)